# python:tensorflow 2.x : model.fit: ValueError: Shapes (50, 3, 10) and (50, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Can I put arrays as labels when I use the function of fit in tensorflow?
the following is my code:

```
from generate_captcha import generateCaptcha
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Conv2D,BatchNormalization,Activation,MaxPool2D,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import os
import numpy as np
def load_train_data():
    g=generateCaptcha()
    image_data,captcha_data=g.gen_captcha()
    for i in range(199):
        x,y=g.gen_captcha()
        image_data=np.concatenate((image_data,x),axis=0)
        captcha_data=np.concatenate((captcha_data,y),axis=0)
        print(i)
    return image_data,captcha_data


class Captcha_model(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.c1=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='SAME')
        self.p1=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2)
        self.d1=Dropout(0.2)
        self.c2=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='SAME')
        self.p2=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2)
        self.d2=Dropout(0.2)
        self.c3=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',padding='SAME')
        self.p3=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2)
        self.d3=Dropout(0.2)
        self.flatten=Flatten()
        self.f1=Dense(1024,activation='relu')
        self.d4=Dropout(0.2)
        self.f2=Dense(3,activation='softmax')

    def call(self,x):
        x=self.c1(x)
        x=self.p1(x)
        x=self.d1(x)
        x=self.c2(x)
        x=self.p2(x)
        x=self.d2(x)
        x=self.c3(x)
        x=self.p3(x)
        x=self.d3(x)
        x=self.flatten(x)
        x=self.f1(x)
        x=self.d4(x)
        y=self.f2(x)

        return y


def train_model():
    image_data,captcha_data=load_train_data()
    print("image_data:",image_data.shape)
    print("captcha_data:",captcha_data.shape)

    model=Captcha_model()
 
 
 
 
 
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

    checkpoint_save_path="./checkpoint/train_captcha.ckpt"
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_save_path+'.index'):
        print('-------------load the model-----------------')
        model.load_weights(checkpoint_save_path)
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_save_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 save_best_only=True)

    history = model.fit(image_data, captcha_data, batch_size=50, epochs=200, validation_freq=1,
                        callbacks=[cp_callback])
    model.summary()
```

the captcha_label's shape is (batch_size,the len of captcha,the classes of characters)（which is(50,3,10) in title).the prediction's shape is(batch_size, the prediction of captcha)(which is (50,3)in the title).
how can I make them compatible with each other?

the following is my repos used above:

```
from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
import random
import string 

class generateCaptcha():
    def __init__(self,width=160,height=60,char_num=3,
                characters=string.digits):  #+string.ascii_lowercase
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.captcha_len=char_num
        self.characters=characters
        self.kinds=len(characters)
    def gen_captcha(self,batch_size=50):
        Image_data=np.zeros([batch_size,self.height,self.width,1])
        Captcha_data=np.zeros([batch_size,self.captcha_len,self.kinds])
        container=np.zeros((self.height,self.width),dtype=np.uint8)
        generator=ImageCaptcha(width=self.width,height=self.height)
        while True:
            for i in range(batch_size):
                captcha_str=''.join(random.sample(self.characters,self.captcha_len))
                container=generator.generate_image(captcha_str).convert('L')
                container_data=np.array(container.getdata())
                Image_data[i]=np.reshape(container_data,[self.height,self.width,1])/255.0
                for j,ch in enumerate(captcha_str):
                    Captcha_data[i,j,self.characters.find(ch)]=1
                #Captcha_data_=np.reshape(Captcha_data,(batch_size,self.captcha_len,self.kinds))
            return Image_data,Captcha_data

    def decode_captcha(self,capt_data):
        capt_data=np.reshape(capt_data,(len(capt_data),self.captcha_len,self.kinds))
        return ''.join(self.characters[x] for x in np.argmax(capt_data,axis=2))

    def get_parameter(self):
        return self.width,self.height,self.captcha_len,self.characters,self.kinds

    def gen_test_captcha(self):
        Image_data=np.zeros([self.height,self.width,1])
        Captcha_data=np.zeros([self.captcha_len,self.kinds])
        container=np.zeros((self.height,self.width),dtype=np.uint8)
        generator=ImageCaptcha(width=self.width,height=self.height)
        
        captcha_str=''.join(random.sample(self.characters,self.captcha_len))
        container=generator.generate_image(captcha_str).convert('L')
        container_data=np.array(container.getdata())
        Image_data=np.reshape(container_data,[self.height,self.width,1])/255.0
        for j,ch in enumerate(captcha_str):
            Captcha_data[j,self.characters.find(ch)]=1
        Captcha_data=np.reshape(Captcha_data,(self.captcha_len,self.kinds))
        container.save(captcha_str+'.jpg')
        return Image_data,Captcha_data
```

the details of error are:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zhanggenxi\Desktop\sublime\train_captcha.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\zhanggenxi\Desktop\sublime\train_captcha.py", line 76, in main
    train_model()
  File "C:\Users\zhanggenxi\Desktop\sublime\train_captcha.py", line 70, in train_model
    history = model.fit(image_data, captcha_data, batch_size=50, epochs=200, validation_freq=1,
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 505, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2657, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:532 train_step  **
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:205 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:143 __call__
        losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:246 call
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1527 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4561 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    D:\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1117 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (50, 3, 10) and (50, 3) are incompatible
```

Comment: Without a traceback (full error) I don't know where you have a problem.  But a `(50,3,1)` shape array `broadcasts` with a `(50,3,10)` (in `numpy`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the shape of parameter in “Dense" is (3,). How can I transform if to (3,1,)?

Comment: the question has been resolved.In tf.keras.layers.reshape can help me reshape the prediction label